# Postman : OAuth2 : get New Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, google-console-developer

I'm trying to test my API with POSTMAN and I have an issue about getting "New Access Token" in authorisation tab in POSTMAN (OAuth2),

So my application is already registred in google console, and I use passport with google strategy to connect and It worked for me.

I also registred the postman in google console:
[image]

And now I'm trying to get the access Token and I think the problem is in "Auth URL" and "Access Token URL" :
[image]

Please help me!

Comment: Which version of Postman do you have - The Auth feature has been changed recently and that seems like the older version. http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/11/04/postman-makes-authorization-stronger-and-easier/

Comment: @DannyDainton : Postman Version : 5.4.0

Comment: 5.5.0 is the newest version but that shouldn’t matter in this case. Is there anything in here that can help https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

Comment: You might need to do some more research on this question - there are multiple posts SO related to the same thing.

Comment: @DannyDainton I'll look into that link.